# Open MATLAB File(.m) using java

Tags: java, matlab

I want to open MATLAB File(.m) using Java

I know MATLAB API.

It's a shame, but I don't know how to use it. How can I open MATLAB File(.m) using MATLAB API?

What should I do?

If possible, can you show an example code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[calling matlab function in java](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html)

1-first, add matlab as an Environment variable in windows.
in win10: search Environment variable,  Edit environment variable, system variables, path, edit, new, ...
add [matlabroot]/bin/win64 to the path variables.

2-import matlab engine in your java class and use MatlabEngine and its functions :(eval,evalAsync,feval,...) :

```
import com.mathworks.engine.*; //import engine

public class javaEvalFunc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try{
            MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab(); 
            eng.evalAsync("[X, Y] = meshgrid(-2:0.2:2);");
            eng.evalAsync("Z = X .* exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);");
            Object[] Z = eng.getVariable("Z");
            eng.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

3-to call a specific .m routine, call it with its full path with eval,...

```
eng.eval("c:\temp\myroutine");
```

Comment: Thank u.
But This is only API usage.
I wanna know to open created .m file in java class.

.m file is "c:\user\hunny\desktop\test.m"

Comment: @hunny you want to open m-file to see its content and/or edit it?

Comment: yes I want to open m-file to see its content and/or edit it.

Comment: @hunny m-files are simple text-file, you could open them like any other text files in java

Comment: thank you, then how do I draw matlap graph using m-files?

Comment: @hunny actually i am confused, please clearly state the problem with an example in another question. tnx